# Phonon-electron interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics

[image: Feynman diagram]

Does anyone know the physical quantity of the $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{q}$ vectors in this Feynman diagram of a phonon-electron interaction?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "physical quantity", but this typically represents two electrons (straight lines) scattering via a phonon (wiggly line).

Comment: I'm sorry. Thanks for your reply. I guess the vectors represent momentum, is this true?

Comment: Yes, the k and q vectors typically represent the crystal momentum.

Comment: Thanks for the help!